# Get the number of Requests in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, backend

I would like to know if is there any way of getting the total number of request in a certain path with Expressjs?

Comment: Why not maintain a counter variable and do `counter++` inside route? @Nicekor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not to count it by yourself?

```
let pingCount = 0;
app.get('/ping',(req, res) => {
  pingCount++;
  res.send(`ping world for ${pingCount} times`);
});
```

Comment: I have done that way, was curious if there was any specific method to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I created a middleware that will attach with all routes and count visits. Put this before your routes in app.js

```
let page_visits = {};
let visits = function (req, res, next) {
  let counter = page_visits[req.originalUrl];
  if(counter || counter === 0) {
    page_visits[req.originalUrl] = counter + 1;
  } else {
    page_visits[req.originalUrl] = 1;
  }
  console.log(req.originalUrl, counter);
  next();
};

app.use(visits);
```

Comment: I have done that way, was curious if there was any specific method that would return it. Thank you!

Comment: @Nicekor Good to hear that. If you find the answer helpful please upvote it.

Comment: Shouldn't the else statement set the total to 1?

Answer (score 1):

```
let count=0;

function countMiddleware(req,res,next){
count++;
if(next)next();
}

app.use(countMiddleware);
```

function countMiddleware is acting as middleware ,so it will be executed for every request.count variable is incremented for every request that is logged on your server